# Library build error on Android Compile SDK 30

Tags: android, android-studio, build-error

I need your support, I'm very new.
where am i doing wrong?

Gradle area as belowe:

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mayapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

My dependencies area as abowe:

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:30.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:30.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:30.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
```

Error when building or running the application.
The error line is as follows:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:30.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:30.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:support-media-compat:30.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: There is no version `30.0.0` of those libraries, and those libraries were discontinued years ago. "I'm very new" -- make sure that you are learning Android app development from up-to-date sources. If it helps, [here are free books that I wrote on Android app development](https://commonsware.com/catalog), and the key ones (*Elements of Android Jetpack* and *Exploring Android*) were updated last year.

Answer (score 0):

Do this - Right click on the folder that contains Java files of your project in Android Studio. Usually the folder will be like **com > somename > projectname**

Now click on **REFACTOR > Migrate to Android X** this will check all the places for older android dependencies. And then click **Do Refactor**. Now it will ask for backup. Choose folder for backup. After your project will be converted to AndroidX which supports SDK 28 and above.